# Why does Helvetica Neue render terribly on Windows 7 (in chrome)?

Tags: windows

I installed Helvetica Neue for some work in PhotoShop, now FaceBook has decided to start using it as a default and it looks terrible in Chrome. Why is this? Is there any way I can work around this, i.e. make it not look terrible so that I can use it by default.

[image: look at how terrible it's rendered]

Comment: Hi John, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: What source did you install it from?